# pgfplot: multi column legend entries with marker in first line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I shift the line/marker (that shows the color of the curve) in the first line of a multi line legend entry?

```
    \documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      legend style={cells={align=left}}
   ]  
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{a\\b};
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{c\\d};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then insert multi line legend entry you can put entry a and c in single line and add `\addlegendimage{empty legend}` for legend entry b and d

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={cells={align=left}}]  
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{a}
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{b}
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{c}
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{d}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or to control vertical alignment of legend entry you can add `legend style={nodes={yshift=-.5\baselineskip}}`

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={cells={align=left},nodes={yshift=-.5\baselineskip}}
   ]  
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{a\\b};
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{c\\d};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]